# cannot get the textarea value using with method in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

// post/createPlay

```
<div id="code">
<h2 >源代码</h2>
<textarea id="textArea" onkeyup="runCode()" >@if(isset($code)) {{$code}} @endif</textarea>
</div>

<div id="result">
<h2 >显示效果</h2>
<iframe  src="about:blank" id="iFrame" contentEditable="true" ></iframe>
</div>

</div><!--end of playMain-->
```

//page form

```
<form action="http://localhost/html5lav/public/post/playAction" method="post">
<textarea name="playCode">  
    &lt;!DOCTYPE&gt;
    &lt;html&gt;
    &lt;body&gt;

      &lt;div class="circle red"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
      &lt;div class="circle green"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;

    &lt;/body&gt;
    &lt;/html&gt;
</textarea> 
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

//PostController

```
public function createPlay(){
    return View::make('frontend.post.play');
}
public function playAction(){ 
  $code = Input::get('playCode');
  return Redirect::route('createPlay')->with('code', $code);
}
```

//Route

```
  Route::get('post/createPlay', array(
   'uses' => 'PostController@createPlay',
   'as' => 'createPlay'
  ));

  Route::post('post/playAction', array(
   'uses' => 'PostController@playAction',
   'as' => 'playAction'
  ));
```

what i wanna do is to get the textarea value from the form page, and  transfer the "Input::get('playCode')" data to the 'post/createPlay' page through the'with' method so that in the 'post/createPlay' page, we can have the data tranferred in textarea(whose id is textArea) and shows in the iframe element using js by obtaining the data again from the textarea in the same page.  but i tried many times ,it didn't succeed. the variable $code is just empty.

Comment: there exits data in the  textarea  of the form page. I use &lt;..&gt; so that it can show the html in the real page. What i need to do is to click the submit button, and transfer the data to the 'post/createPlay' page and then show the same data in the textarea of  the 'post/createPlay' page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing anything to the view. You need to send `$code` to the view either with the 2nd parameter of `View::make()` or using the View's `with` method.

You're sending a redirect with data which flashes said data to the session so you can retrieve it from the session and send it to the view as follows.

```
return View::make('frontend.post.play', ['code' => session('code')]);
```

- [Flash data](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#flash-data)
- [Passing data to views](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#passing-data-to-views)

Comment: Sorry,I have just strarted to learn laravel and it's a bit difficult for me  to understanding this sentence:You're sending a redirect with data which flashes said data to the session so you can retrieve it from the session and send it to the view as follows.can you explain a bit detailed please,thanks

Comment: I thought i have passed the data in the 'PostController@playAction',  sholud't it pass the data to the redirected url:  post/createPlay?

Comment: Redirect->with flashes data to the session so that it is available on the next page loaded. Flashing data means it's only available for one page load then cleared. What you've done is pass your code to the next load, but then not told that data to be sent to the view. Yes, it's available in the `createPlay` controller method but you don't do anything with it. using `$code = session('code')` will load the data from the session. You then need to pass that variable to the view.

Comment: 'pass your code to the next load' here means i have passes the data to the 'post/createPlay' page . the only thing i need to do is to get the data from the session, thanks.

Comment: COOL,I have done what you have said and It works. YOU are awesome. AND i will check the links you give me. Thanks,really appreciated^-^.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted.